# Visual Studio 2019 - Auto Check-out certain files

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

WE have been having this issue with our Visual Studio 2019, certain files are automatically checked-out on all users when they load the company solution.

I am not sure why but it happens to all every user in the company and on all computers, as soon as you load the single solution that we have, files from Multiple projects are checked-out and they are always those 12 files,

When you compare these files with latest version / Server version you see no difference.

[AutoCheckedout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDEFJ.png)

BTW we are using Azure-DevOps Server but we had this issue since TFS 2017 Update 2

[When Unbinding and rebinding / reloading Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPCbQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it sounds like the solution isn't “bound” to the version control provider correctly.

From Visual Studio's main File menu, select **File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control**

[image]

You'll see this dialog:

[image]

Make sure the server bindings are correct and that each solution/project is “connected”.

If everything looks like fine, then try to **unbind any projects** that are bound but not working correctly.

Bind all projects again that are now unbound. Which may do the trick.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thank you for responding, I've tried that. when i launched visual studio and loaded the project again, got the same issue:
U_F_C_U_A_ThisAddIn.Designer.xml, U_F_C_U_A_ThisAddIn.vb have been automatically checked out for editing.
U_F_C_U_A_ThisAddIn.Designer.vb has been automatically checked out for editing.
U_F_C_U_A_ThisAddIn.Designer.xml, U_F_C_U_A_ThisAddIn.vb have been automatically checked out for editing.....

Comment: I've added an image in the original post, please have a look, its an error that i guess with the same files that are automatically checked out, when i was performing your "unbind" rebind steps

Comment: Hi @AasimShakilPathan , have you checked in all files before unbinding and rebinding? If this is still not work. There maybe something wrong of your local folder mapping with server side folder. Try to change to use another local windows folder to store your `.sln` files. After this bind your solution to TFS server again. Compare changes  and ignore all. More details please take a look at the solution from *Muflix* and *Jeb50* in this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42438683/the-item-is-already-under-source-control-at-selected-location

Comment: Hi @Patrick, yes I did check in before unbinding and rebinding. I have a question. We have these custom Office Addin's that we are developing. it seems like the solution doesn't error out on loading Excel AddIn even though its the same file names as the ones listed above. Is there any reason its unable to do so because of conflicting file names?
 U_F_C_U_A_ThisAddIn.vb < Excel
 U_F_C_U_A_ThisAddIn.vb < Word
 U_F_C_U_A_ThisAddIn.vb < Outlook
 U_F_C_U_A_ThisAddIn.vb < PowerPoint
 U_F_C_U_A_ThisAddIn.vb < Visio
the .sln is able to load Excel without any problems.

Comment: Hi  @AasimShakilPathan, A check-in lock is added based on file extension for files which may be difficult to merge. You can change the list of file extensions by going to:
1. The home page of the Team Explorer
2. Click Settings
3. Under "Team Project Collection," select Source Control. The Source Control Settings dialog will appear. The first tab, "File Types," lets you control this behavior. If "File Merging" is "Disabled", then that means automatic locking at checkout is enabled. To stop getting locks at checkout, you'll actually want to enable file merging for .dll files.

Comment: Not sure if totally get your point, if not please also share a screenshot to make issue more clearly. Besides, for your original issue, please also try to change to use another local windows folder to store your .sln files. After this, bind your solution to TFS server again. Compare changes and ignore all.  Then just check it again. Hope it works

Comment: Ok so i found out there are 4 Warnings that are related to these projects when the solution is loaded. the warning is "The generated files could not be loaded and have been recreated" its possible that the files are checked out due to this. but i am unable to figure our why.

Comment: Hi @AasimShakilPathan According to your description, that maybe a reason. But I have never met such situation. Looks like a  issue in Visual Studio side. Try to reload your project and rebuild the solution. https://www.howtosolutions.net/2013/02/solving-project-file-error-could-not-find-part-of-the-path-with-visual-studio/  Also try to clear TFS and Visual Studio Cache:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/willy-peter_schaub/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not

Comment: Hi, Nope it hasn't helped, I've recreated the entire solution but the problem still exists. removed the project from TFS entirely as well.

Comment: Hi @AasimShakilPathan Thanks for your kindly update. What if try this workaround, , go to Tools, Options, Source Control, Environment and change the Checked-in items for Saving and Editing to "Prompt for check out" or "Do nothing " rather than the default which is "Check out automatically". Details check the screenshot in this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7120349/5391065  Did this do the trick?

Comment: When i set it to "Prompt for check out" and loaded the solution it prompted me 12 times to checkout the files.
When i set it to "Do nothing" the files were not checked out on loading the solution which was great but I was unable to edit any project files automatically by starting to type into it directly unless I first "Check out for Edit Now" on the file so this option is not of any use to us.