# force visual studio to auto checkout a file (appdef.xml)

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I could not find any post for this..

We have Azure DevOps for our solutions, and we use Visual Studio Community 2019. v 16.8.4
I, and others keep forgetting to checkout and increment a file name appdef.xml, before we add files to Git.

How can I make it always be checked out automatically as soon as we check out any other file in a solution, or even better if possible to auto increment the last number in this tag? Is this a Git feature maybe?

`<version>1.0.1.3</version>`

If this is a duplicate post, please just close it, and point me in the right direction

- When I say checkout, I mean "Changes" as in provided pic.

[image]

Comment: Please be more explicit in what you understand with "checkout" this file because with git their not this notion of "checkout" (It seems you give it the meaning of TFVC). With git a file is either seen modified or not. So nothing to checkout and no that's not a git feature. You should find a way to generate this version (based on git commits like https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion could do...)

Comment: It seems that you are using TFVC not Git repository. From Visual Studio's main File menu, select File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control, make sure the server bindings are correct and that each solution/project is “connected”. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60648596/visual-studio-2019-auto-check-out-certain-files and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff550ed8-a1d0-45d3-b9ba-90cb8cac4617/project-files-of-our-solution-are-automatically-checked-out-what-is-happening?forum=tfsversioncontrol for more details.

Answer (score 0):

For Git repository, if this file is changed(created, removed, edited), this file will appear in changes set, and will be committed to remote repository, unless this file is ignored in `.gitignore` file.

Thus, there must be changes in the `appdef.xml` file and it is not ignored, so you can commit it.

Comment: Okay, but the whole point was for it to be automatically atleast "changed" and ideally incremented.

Comment: In that way, you should find a way to generate this version (based on git commits like github.com/GitTools/GitVersion could do as  Philippe suggested.